# How to display a list as 3 columns for lg screens and 1 column for sm screens

Tags: javascript, css, size, screen

On a computer, my list looks like:
[image]

But on a phone, it only shows the 1st column and doesn't continue the list as a 1-column list.

I'm using Bootstrap and my code looks like:

```
 <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-start">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="p-3">

                        <b>Statewide Texas Sites</b><br />
                        <a href="https://www.touringtexas.com/" target="_top">Touring Texas</a>
                        <br />
                        <a href="https://www.texas-lakes.net/" target="_top">Texas Lakes</a>
                        <br />

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
                    <div class="p-3">

                        <b>Texas Tourist Areas</b><br />
                        <a href="https://www.highlandlakes.com/" target="_top">Highland Lakes</a>
                        <br />
                        <a href="https://www.hill-country.net/" target="_top">Hill Country Network</a>
                        <br />

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
                    <div class="p-3">

                        <b>Texas Lakes</b><br />
                        <a href="https://www.highlandlakes.net/lakeaustin/" target="_top">Lake Austin</a>
                        <br />
                        <a href="https://www.lake-bridgeport.com/" target="_top">Lake Bridgeport</a>
                        <br />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

İt should work fine, looks like you have something wrong with your setup, first I can think is viewport, check if you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` in your head.

See example working on mobile and desk.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Sticky Footer Template for Bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<section>
<div class="container">
<div class="row align-items-start">
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="p-3">

   <b>Statewide Texas Sites</b><br />
   <a href="https://www.touringtexas.com/" target="_top">Touring Texas</a>
   <br />
   <a href="https://www.texas-lakes.net/" target="_top">Texas Lakes</a>
   <br />

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
  <div class="p-3">

   <b>Texas Tourist Areas</b><br />
   <a href="https://www.highlandlakes.com/" target="_top">Highland Lakes</a>
   <br />
   <a href="https://www.hill-country.net/" target="_top">Hill Country Network</a>
   <br />

  </div>
 </div>


 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
  <div class="p-3">

   <b>Texas Lakes</b><br />
   <a href="https://www.highlandlakes.net/lakeaustin/" target="_top">Lake Austin</a>
   <br />
   <a href="https://www.lake-bridgeport.com/" target="_top">Lake Bridgeport</a>
   <br />

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
 
  </body>
</html>
```